# How to draw a circle using gl.POINTS in webgl?

Tags: javascript, opengl, webgl

I am going through this [tutorial](http://studentprojects.co.in/downloads/url.php?url=https://app.box.com/s/k8jaxclxuzo1wrinnn5m) and it has been implemented in OpenGL, 
I am trying to implement the same in WebGL but not sure which one is shader and what is cpu part of it , can anyone suggest me?

Code :

```
void circle::createcircle (int k, int r, int h)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<1000;i++){
        x=r*cos(i)-h;
        y = r * sin(i) + k;
        glVertex3f(x + k,y-h,0);
        x = r * cos(i + 0.1) - h;
        y = r * sin(i + 0.1) + k;
        glVertex3f(x + k,y - h,0);
    }
    glEnd(); 
}
```

Comment: This is using old-and-busted legacy glBegin/glEnd. Nothing of this is shader (glBegin/glEnd predates shaders by about 8 years).

Comment: Nothing about this is the correct approach for WebGL.  You should look for a different example, such as [how to draw a circle with a triangle fan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32780958/836708), or how to inscribe a circle on a quad using a shader.

Comment: @emackey I saw that link before asking the question as well. The answer has javascript Array's push method which is used with shader code of vec2, which is very confusing for me to understand. Can you please add a pseudocode for me, I will work on that